# Como saber qual a palavra mais usada em todos os registros

Tags: php

Eu estou fazendo um sistema de top trendig, porém estou muito confuso: Como eu faço para o select puxar apenas as 10 palavras mais usadas em todos os registros.

Porém, as palavras estão em uma coluna e separadas por uma virgula.

OBS: Estou utilizando PHP 5.3

```
Tabela posts
Estrutura: 
id
post_id
post
author_id
author
hashtags
date
```

Comment: Coloca na pergunta a estrutura da tabela e exemplos de dados que estariam armazenados. Você tentou alguma coisa? Pelo menos descreva como você acha que pode ser feito.

Comment: Existe alguma possibilidade de você jogar essas palavras em uma tabela auxiliar, ou trabalhar com elas em json?

Comment: Não está claro como é a estrutura, inviabilizando uma resposta objetiva. Por hora, veja se isso pode ser útil: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748276

Comment: Gabriel, no caso a coluna é a `hashtags`? Já cogitou em criar uma relação muitos para muitos entre a tabela `posts` e uma tabela `hashtags`? Provavelmente a solução ficaria mais semântica e seria possível (acredito eu) resolver o problema apenas com SQL.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Porém, já tenho um sistema que separa as tags de dentro do texto do `post` e adiciona na coluna `hashtags`, já quando o post é inserido na tabela posts.

Answer (score 6):

Você precisa de um dicionário.

Interessantemente, em PHP arrays podem funcionar como dicionários. Descobri isso agora, pesquisando para responder a pergunta. Então vamos começar:

```
$dicionario = array();
```

A lógica é a seguinte: faça um dicionário onde as chaves são as palavras, e o valor é a quantidade de ocorrências.

Como cada registro tem várias palavras separadas por vírgulas, vamos começar extraindo as palavras de cada registro. Na maioria das linguagens a gente chama isso de dividir (`split`), mas como PHP é coisa de terrorista nele a gente usa a função `explode`:

```
$palavras = explode(",", $registro);
```

E então a gente inclui as palavras no dicionário da seguinte forma: se a chave não existir, ela é criada com valor zero. Em seguida, independente de existir ou não, incrementamos seu valor.

```
foreach ($palavras as $chave) {
    if (!$dicionario[$chave]) {
        $dicionario[$chave] = 0;
    }
    $dicionario[$chave]++;
}
```

Note que temos que fazer a explosão e a adição ao dicionário uma vez para cada registro.

Finalmente, precisamos pegar os registros com os dez maiores valores. O algoritmo abaixo remove os dez maiores valores do dicionário enquanto os inclui de forma ordenada em outro dicionário.

```
$dezMaiores = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $maiorValor = 0;
    $maiorChave = "";
    foreach ($dicionario as $chave => $valor) {
        if ($valor > $maiorValor) {
            $maiorValor = $valor;
            $maiorChave = $chave;
        }
    }
    $dezMaiores[$i] = $maiorChave;
    unset($dicionario[$maiorChave]);
}
```

Agora você pode utilizar as dez expressões mais usadas no seu sistema :)

Comment: Funciona no php 5.3?

Comment: Teste a solução só que não está aparecendo as palavras.

Answer (score 3):

Outra solução executando toda a lógica no PHP é utilizar as funções nativas [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-merge.php) e [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-map.php) para criar a lista de palavras, a função [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-count-values.php) para calcular a frequência de cada palavra e a função [`arsort`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.arsort.php) para ordená-las de forma decrescente.

```
<?php

$rows = [
    "abacate,banana,caqui",
    "banana,melão,goiaba",
    "laranja,banana,abacate"
];

$palavras = array_merge(
    ...array_map(
        function ($value) { 
            return explode(',', $value); 
        }, 

        $rows
    )
);

$palavras = array_count_values($palavras);

arsort($palavras);

print_r($palavras);
```

> A solução acima utiliza o *splat operator*, portanto só funciona em versões PHP 5.6+.

A saída produzida é:

```
Array
(
    [banana] => 3
    [abacate] => 2
    [caqui] => 1
    [melão] => 1
    [goiaba] => 1
    [laranja] => 1
)
```

Comment: Preciso de uma solução que funcione em php 5.3.

Comment: @GabrielHenrique então coloque isso na pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

```
$link = new mysqli ("localhost", "USUARIO", "SENHA", "NOME_BANCO");

$query = "SELECT Nome_Coluna FROM Nome_Tabela";

$results = mysqli_query($link,$query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {

  $words .= $row["Nome_Coluna"].",";

}

$palavras = explode(',', $words);

//numero total de palavras
//echo count($palavras); 

$ocorrencias = array();

for($i = 0; $i<count($palavras); $i++){
    $palavra = $palavras[$i];

      // Evitar erros Undefined index vide OBS no final da resposta
      if (!isset($ocorrencias[$palavra])) {
          $ocorrencias[$palavra] = 0;
      }

    $ocorrencias[$palavra]++;
}

arsort($ocorrencias);

//mostra todo o array estruturado
//var_dump($ocorrencias);

    //mostra os dez primeiros valores e respectivas chaves
    $i=0;
     foreach($ocorrencias as $chave => $valor){
            if($i < 10){  
                echo $chave.' - '.$valor.'<br>';
            }
            $i=$i+1;
        }
```

> OBS: Na primeira palavra, `$ocorrencias` é uma lista vazia e quando você faz `$ocorrencias[$palavra]` você estará acessando uma chave inexistente. Para evitar o erro, basta verificar se a chave existe e, se não existir, criá-la com o valor zero.
>   [**Fonte**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220237/evitar-v%C3%A1rios-php-notice-undefined-index-dentro-de-um-loop-for/220250#220250)

Comment: Quando eu coloco as info da db às palavras não aparecem.

Comment: @GabrielHenrique na conexão?

Comment: Não é na conexão. As palavras mais usadas é que não estão aparecendo.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Ao invés de deixar um link com o esclarecimento, porque você não escreve um com suas palavras? -Da revisão.

Comment: A resposta não é dada por link, parte da resposta é que remete para um esclarecimento mais detalhado, alias, essa parte foi uma pergunta de minha autoria e respondida pelo Anderson Carlos Woss. É normal que nas respostas se coloquem links para maiores detalhes em algumas partes da resposta..

Comment: Se formos pensar que algum dia as paginas referenciadas possam não existir mais, então você deveria copiar o conteudo desses links DateTime, DateTime.Parse, ToString, WriteLine e ReadLine.dado na sua resposta e colar nesse post  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/223736/fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-datetime-c/223740#223740