# Evitar vários PHP Notice: Undefined index: dentro de um loop for

Tags: php, mysqli

A variável `$words` concatena o resultado de uma consulta em uma coluna de uma tabela onde as palavras são separadas por virgula.

Só que ao rodar o script para cada palavra dentro do for é gerado um  `PHP Notice:  Undefined index: agua in ....`

Se há 50 palavras vão ser gerados 50 `PHP Notice:  Undefined index: PALAVRA_DO_FOR in ...`

```
$palavras = explode(',', $words);
$ocorrencias = array();

for($i = 0; $i<count($palavras); $i++){
   $palavra = $palavras[$i];
   $ocorrencias[$palavra]++;
}
```

Como evitar esses `PHP Notice:  Undefined index: ...`?

PHP Version 5.4.43

Comment: posso saber o porque do negativado? eu deveria saber resolver esse tipo de duvida? Procurei relacionadas e não achei

Comment: Verifica se a chave existe com `isset` e, se não existir, crie-a antes de utilizá-la.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss não entendi como fazer isso, poderia postar como resposta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro ocorre porque o PHP tenta acessar uma chave do *array* que pode não exisitir inicialmente. Por exemplo, na primeira palavra, `$ocorrencias` é uma lista vazia e quando você faz `$ocorrencias[$palavra]` você estará acessando uma chave inexistente. Para contornar o erro, basta verificar se a chave existe e, se não existir, criá-la com o valor zero.

```
<?php

$words = "stack,overflow,em,portugûes";
$palavras = explode(',', $words);
$ocorrencias = array();

for($i = 0; $i < count($palavras); $i++){

    $palavra = $palavras[$i];

    // Se a chave não existir, crie-a com valor zero:
    if (!isset($ocorrencias[$palavra])) {
        $ocorrencias[$palavra] = 0;
    }

    $ocorrencias[$palavra]++;

}

print_r($ocorrencias);
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/nbHvBo).

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma de resolver esse problema é inicializar o array de ocorrências com todos o elementos já zerados, com a função [`array_fill_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php) o primeiro argumento é o array que será transforma nas chaves do array de saida, o segundo é o valor padrão para todos os elementos.

Depois pode trocar o `for` pelo `foreach` e só incrementar a chave.

```
$words = 'teste,abc,2015,teste,13,abc,2015';

$palavras = explode(',', $words);
$ocorrencias = array_fill_keys($palavras, 0);

foreach($palavras as $item){
    $ocorrencias[$item]++;
}
```

Retorno:

```
Array
(
    [teste] => 2
    [abc] => 2
    [2015] => 2
    [13] => 1
)
```

Answer (score -3):

Eu poderia muito bem lhe sugerir para desativar as mensagens de aviso do PHP no seu script desta forma:

```
ini_set('display_errors', FALSE);
```

Mas não seria bem conveniente, pois o mais adequado mesmo é trabalhar seu script para que contenha um código limpo, pois é melhor corrigir o erro do que escondê-lo. Para isso basta utilizar uma função do PHP (**isset**) para verificar se o índice existe antes de tentar utilizá-lo.

Exemplo:

```
$palavras = explode(',', $words);
$ocorrencias = array();

for($i = 0; $i<count($palavras); $i++){
  if (isset($palavras[$i])) {
    $palavra = $palavras[$i];
    $ocorrencias[$palavra]++;
  }
}
```