# Função DateTime C#

Tags: c#, datetime

Me deparei com um exercício no qual deve-se converter a data do formato AM/PM para o formato militar (24h).

Então, suponha que o usuário digite 07:05:45PM, o programa deverá retornar 19:05:45.

Não gosto muito de procurar soluções na internet, mas eu não fazia a mínima ideia de como resolver essa questão e me deparei com a seguinte solução:

```
 Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine()).ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
```

Mesmo buscando na internet, não consegui entender como esse método funciona.
Vocês poderiam me explicar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, este é o código:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine()).ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
```

Agora vamos quebrar ele em partes e ver o que cada comando faz e como funciona:

```
Console.ReadLine() //Lê uma string do console (input)

DateTime.Parse() //Converte a string para o tipo de variável DateTime

ToString("HH:mm:ss") //Converte a variável DateTime para string novamente, mas agora respeitando os seguintes parâmetros:
                     // "hora:minutos:segundos" (padrão brasileiro / 24h)

Console.WriteLine() //Escreve a string no console (output)
```

#### Documentações:

[DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx), [DateTime.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx), [ToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx), [WriteLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.console.writeline(v=vs.110).aspx) e [ReadLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime.Parse
```

Aqui ele está transformando sua entrada de dados de usuário que é no formato texto(string) para o formado de data e tempo.

Depois ele retorna o formato de Data para texto, já usando o format: `ToString("HH:mm:ss")`
que seria basicamente, tansformar o texto em um formato de data e hora.

Da uma lida aqui, pode lhe ajudar a esclarecer melhor: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Você também pode utilizar o `ParseExact` quando quiser converter uma data de um formato específico:

> Utilização: DateTime.ParseExact(string valor, string formato, IFormatProvider)

Formato: Para seu caso, podemos utilizar o formato `hh:mm:ss tt` onde **hh** são para o valor das horas com dois dígitos e escala 0-12 (**HH** é para o valor das horas com dois dígitos e escala 0-24), **mm** são para os minutos, **ss** os segundos, e finalmente o **tt** para o período (AM/PM).

```
            string dataPm = "07:01:02 PM";

            DateTime dt24 = DateTime.ParseExact(dataPm, "hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            string resultado = dt24.ToString();
            //24/07/2017 19:01:02
```

Comment: Esse código é mais correto do que o código na pergunta, e a sua resposta é a melhor em código, mas infelizmente ela não oferece nenhuma explicação. Se você puder escrever sobre - e principalmente explicar a diferença entre `h` e  `H` para o método `ParseExact` - terá meu voto.

Comment: @Renan estou complementando, só um momento